# How can I turn my Wix website full responsive?

Tags: web, responsive-design, editor, velo

I created a website with wix editor (not wix ADI) and it works well in computers and mobile version.
The fact is that it is not responsive with tablets, and I already tried all the editor options and could not solve it. Should I add/embed a specific code in order to be responsive in other devices?

Thank you.